# Can't play quicktime stream video on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: firefox, quicktime

I've installed Ubuntu 15.10 instead of Ubuntu 14.04. After that I can't play quicktime stream video from my video surveillance in Firefox (and in chromium and google-chrome too).

I tried to install browser-plugin-vlc, xine-plugin but unsuccessfully.